# Push local git repo to server via ssh

Tags: ssh, git

So I have a local repo and a server with git installed and a git user.

I want to send (push) the repo to the server. When I simply login to the server via `ssh` I have to specify my .pem file and a passphrase.

The following:

```
sudo git push git@333.3.3.3..3:somerepo.git
```

throws this error:

```
 Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Another attempt another error:

```
git push ssh://git@222.2.2.2:somerepo.git
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: Do you get same error when git clone?

Comment: sudo: just trying things.
added as a remote. Didn't help.
Same erro with git clone.

Comment: `sudo` is the cause of more problems than it solves (in the hands of a novice). But the `sudo` down and step away.

Answer (score 2):

Too many questions open for a precise answer.

> sudo git push git@333.3.3.3..3:somerepo.git

Are you sure this is a valid IP address?
(sudo is definitely wrong here.)

> Permission denied (publickey).

Your server seems to allow ssh connection only via publickey.
Did you create a key pair? did you put the public key on the server?
Does `ssh-add` add the key to your agent?

> git push ssh://git@222.2.2.2:somerepo.git
>   ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known

Is this another host? Does it contain a repo, too? Seems like it just does not exist.

How did you create the repository on the server? Are you able to ssh into the server?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure ssh works to the server. Then, go on the server and create a bare repo "mkdir repo", "cd repo", "git init --bare". Then, from your machine you can do a "git push ssh:user@server:repo".

Comment: I'm making the assumption you don't have a repo on the server yet versus having one and trying to push.

Comment: If you ssh to the server, you may get the error “Shell access is disabled.”, this is OK and shows that it is working.